# How to link DB2 tables

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have header and detail table, and the relation ship between those 1:N
both table has auto SEQ number field, i want to link up those two tables using some technique so i can trace back.
I have two solution in my mind, need your help if you advice one from those or another better option.

(1) Use data area and store a 10000000 number to begin with and fetch it for each header insertion and multiple detail insertion ... increase number and update data area.(this case both table will be having there own auto SEQ number and a linked key)
(2) fetch header table SEQ number while inserting record in it and use that as a key in detail table. (this case header will have Auto seq key and detail table will have auto SEQ key and linked key as header table's auto key)

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for a sequence. A sequence is an SQL object that returns the next sequential number each time it is requested. It is implemented in a data area, but that is on no consequence to you. The big thing is that a sequence is created and accessed using SQL.

To create a sequence, in it's simplest form, you issue the following SQL statement:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE NEXT_ORDER_NO;
```

Additional information about creating sequences can be found in the [Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzcsequence.htm).

To generate a number from this sequence you can include `NEXT VALUE FOR <sequence name>` in an SQL statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO ORDER_MASTER (ORDER_NO, CUSTOMER_NO)
  VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR NEXT_ORDER_NO, 15);
```

This inserts a new record into the table ORDER_MASTER with the next order number from the sequence, and the value 15 as the customer number.

To get the most recent value generated from the sequence you use `PREVIOUS VALUE FOR <sequence name>`, like this:

```
INSERT INTO ORDER_DETAIL (ORDER_NO, ORDER_LINE, ITEM_NO)
  VALUES (PREVIOUS VALUE FOR NEXT_ORDER_NO, 1, 'AX14450')
```

This inserts a record into table ORDER_DETAIL with the most recently generated ORDER_NO, an order line of 1, and an item number of 'AX14450'. You can use `PREVIOUS VALUE FOR <sequence name>` as many times as you want, and it will always return the same value. You can also find more information in the [Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzseqref.htm).

There are a few caveats. `NEXT VALUE` and `PREVIOUS VALUE` behave as you would expect, even if multiple jobs are using the same sequence. Job 1 will not have access to Job 2's generated values and vice versa. But this means that depending on how you define the sequence, you could end up with gaps in your sequence numbers, or they could be issued out of sequence. Be sure to read both of the references I provided for more in depth explanations.

---

Edit:

If you don't want to use `NEXT VALUE` directly in your insert, you can also use `VALUES INTO` like this:

```
VALUES NEXT VALUE FOR NEXT_ORDER_NO INTO :<local variable>
```

You can find more info about this statement in the [Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzvalinto.htm).

---

Edit (2)

As an alternative to a sequence, you can use an identity column (this is what it seems you want based on your comments), but you don't have to do anything crazy in your SQL to retrieve the last identity value assigned. Use `IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL` like this:

```
INSERT INTO HTABLE (NAME, AGE) VALUES ('Mark', 51);

INSERT INTO DTABLE (hseq,Address,Zip) 
  VALUES (IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL(),'1701 creek ave', 19670);

INSERT INTO DTABLE (hseq,Address,Zip) 
  VALUES (IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL(), '22701 creek ave', 19270);
```

The value of `IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL()` only changes when an `INSERT` is executed on a table with an identity column. Like `PREVIOUS VALUE`, `IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL()` will return a null if it is not preceded by an `INSERT` on a table with an identity column. And also like `PREVIOUS VALUE`, the `INSERT` must be in the same job as the call to `IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL()` to have any affect.

Find a comparison of identity columns and sequences [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/sqlp/rbafyidentsequence.htm).

Comment: Thanks,

My plan is to have seq generated in DB2 itself and then use it to link the tables as below

Exec sql                                     
SELECT SEQUENCE_NUMBER INTO :W_SEQ 
FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO HTABLE (NAME, AGE) 
VALUES ('Mark', 51));
                       
Exec sql     
INSERT INTO DTABLE (hseq,Address,Zip)                 
VALUES (:W_SEQ,'1701 creek ave', 19670);
                                       
Exec sql                                              
INSERT INTO DTABLE (hseq,Address,Zip)                 
VALUES (:W_SEQ,'22701 creek ave', 19270);

Comment: the results look like this
----Header table---
SEQUENCE_NUMBER  CUSTOMER_NAME  CUSTOMER_AGE                                  
             6      Bill              21    
             7      Mark              51    
----Detail Table ------------
SEQUENCE_NUMBER     HEADER SEQ   CUSTOMER_ADDRESS                                                 
             1               6   1701 park ave       
             2               6   22701 park ave      
             3               7   1701 creek ave      
             4               7   22701 creek ave

Comment: If you use a sequence (the sequence number is still generated and managed within DB2), you don't have to go through all of that. The logic is cleaner and more readable.

Comment: If you are intent on using an identity column, you can use `IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL` to retrieve the most recently assigned identity column value. See the [Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzscaidentity.htm) for more info.

Comment: What if other job insert record before i do Identity_value_Local() in my call.....
This is the service call and many application hitting this program. there are possibility two process at same time can call this service program to insert record.

Comment: `IDENTITY_VALUE_LOCAL` will only return a value generated in the same job as the `INSERT`. If you are inserting the detail in a separate call to your service, Then you can use `VALUES INTO` to retrieve the last identity value into a variable in the call that contains the `INSERT`, then you would want to return the identity value as a result of the `INSERT` call. Still easier to read with `IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL`

Comment: Thanks looks like going to work for me.. i will be inserting header and detail in same program call.